# Class won't show up

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I just had this code working a couple days ago now it is giving me an error:

> Unknown class DraggableImage in Interface Builder file.

I have tried cleaning the file, restarting both my computer and Xcode multiple times, but nothing will work. I know there are questions like this but nothing they have said have worked for me. Also the class isn't in the drop down menu It is in the ViewDidLoad section.

My code:

```
class DraggableImage : UIImageView {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first;
        let location = touch?.location(in: self.superview);
        if location != nil {
            self.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: location!.x-self.frame.size.width, y: location!.y-self.frame.size.height);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In xCode, select the the in the left pane that you are having issues with. With it selected check the contents of 'Target Memebership' in the right pane and ensure that the correct target is selected. When you say it is in the viewDidLoad section... what do you mean? you can't declare a class there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sour your Module is `current - {Your Project}` but not None
[image: expected Module]

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** hmmm... this might not be what you're having trouble with... I'll delete this answer if that's the case.

Search for it as a text string in your whole project. It should show up like this:

[image]